# common strategy for proving a real-valued function that is bounded

Tags: analysis

Yes I'm actually doing a prove on $$f(x)=\frac{x}{1+x^2}$$

but I'm not happy by only solving a particular case.

So, i'm trying to do some conclusion here:

I think one of the condition is to prove the function limits to both infinities need to be smaller than the infinite.

this prevent the function from acting blizzard on both ends, but how to prevent they are acting weird in the middle?

But what else? What are the sufficient and necessary (also the executable) conditions for a real-valued function to be bounded?

The definition of bounded function $|f(x)|\le M,$ for x on the suitable domain is simply impossible to handle when doing a proof, it has (in most cases) $\aleph_1$ cases to prove.

Comment: For this particular case, you can use $|x|<1+x^2$ for all x.  (You are correct that the function cannot have an infinite limit as $x\rightarrow\pm\infty$.)

Comment: when a function is continuous on a compact set(closed and bounded intervals) it is bounded.

Answer (score 0):

There is a standard fact in analysis that a function which is continuous and defined everywhere on some bounded interval $[a,b]$ is bounded.  This can for example be found from an advanced Calculus standpoint in Spivak's *Calculus*. The more sophisticated topological proof observes that $[a,b]$ is compact, thus has has compact image, thus bounded image (if you don't know these types of arguments, don't worry).

Thus if you can prove it is bounded outside of some interval, say $[-N,N]$ and continuous inside, then it will be bounded. So one fast way is to (a) establish continuity (b) prove the limits in both $\pm \infty$ are finite. If you unravel the definition of limit at infinity, you will see this imposes bounds (say fixing $\epsilon = 1$) at each end of the real line beyond some point.